# How to update a Fragment View in Android without changing the current state of the view?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Whenever I click on a refresh button on my fragment and get new set of data, I call this function:

```
public void updateView(User user){
        LinkAdapter linkList = new LinkAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.link_list,user.links, getActivity());
        linkCardView.setAdapter(linkList);


    }
```

This updates the view with new set of links at the top of it, and also drags the view up to the top to show the new links that have been added.

My only problem is I don't want the dragging up to happen. Say the user has scrolled to position B in a listView and then refreshes which results in new data added to the top of the listView, the current View state shouldn't be altered automatically. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: call `linkList.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh or update your lsitview

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new adapter and setting it, when you update the content, I'm guessing user.links, make sure you update whatever array you sent into the adapter, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Comment: Nope, that causes no change.